# Usage of respectively with "or" vs "and"

Tags: word-choice

Is this a correct way of using respectively in the following sentence

The word respectively should link "X" with "above" and "Y with "below".

> X and Y may have incentives to keep and push stock prices above or below thresholds, respectively.

I would like that readers understand it as:

X has only the incentive to push and keep prices above thresholds.

Y has only the incentive to push and keep prices below thresholds.

**Is it better to use "or" or "and" between "above" and "below"?**

Comment: Oops. This should not have been tagged with `single-word-requests` (and, ideally, my single vote should not have resolved this as it did). I have removed the tag. I still believe this is a duplicate, but I'm not convinced enough of that (despite the nearly identical question titles) to have wanted mine to be the sole voice in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

**"Or" probably helps clarity.**

But further clarity could, I think, be achieved by putting **"respectively"** in a different part of the sentence.

The way I would say it is:

*There may be an incentive for X and Y, **respectively** to keep and push stock prices above **or** below thresholds*.

That seems clearer to me, but it is a matter of personal choice, and the way you have it at the moment is perfectly correct.

Comment: Would something like: "  X and Y may have incentives to keep and push stock prices above, respectively, below thresholds. " be a correct option?

Comment: I'm not sure why you place "respectively" in between above and below. To me that is yet more confusion, also unusual and doubtfully grammatical. Why not "X and Y may have incentives to keep and push stock prices respectively above or below thresholds"?